# ¿Cómo puedo mover archivos de imágenes, seleccionadas específicamente, de una carpeta a otra en RStudio?

Tags: r

Quería plantear la siguiente duda si me pueden ayudar:

Tengo una carpeta con más de 1.000 imágenes en formato `jpg`, de esa cantidad deseo seleccionar una lista específica y moverlas a otra carpeta.

Adjunto el código empleado:

```
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = normalizePath("path")) 

setwd("~/ESTADISTICAS/MONITOREO/imagen_2021") #archivo donde se ubican las 
imágenes 
getwd() 

f <- file.path("~/ESTADISTICAS/MONITOREO/imagen_2021", c("A032101359.JPG", "A042100147.JPG", "A042101146.JPG", "A042101493.JPG",  "A042101494.JPG", "A042101993.JPG", "A042102639.JPG", "A042102907.JPG",  "A042103659.JPG")) #lista de archivos a seleccionar 
for (archivo in f){   file.rename(from = archivo, to = paste("~/ESTADISTICAS/MONITOREO/mtras_insat_imagenes", archivo) ) 

}
```

**¿Qué me recomiendan?**, **¿Cómo empezar?**

Soy muy nuevo en programación en R. Gracias

Comment: Por favor [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/451999/edit) tu pregunta para agregar el código que intentaste y así será mejor recibida. Colocarlo como comentario en una respuesta puede hacer que se pierda muy facilmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede usar la función `file.copy()` para copiar o `file.rename()` para mover los archivos. Por ejemplo para copiar un archivo "imagen.jpg" dentro del directorio de trabajo activo a un directorio diferente:

```
file.copy(from = "imagen.jpg", to = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/" )
```

Para mover varios archivos podrías usar un ciclo similar a :

```
lista <- c("imagen1.jpg", "imagen2.jpg")

for (archivo in lista){
  file.rename(from = archivo, to = paste("C:/Users/user/Desktop/", archivo, sep = "") )
}
```

La lista de archivos a moverse podría generarse automáticamente con la función `list.files()`. Por ejemplo, para seleccionar todos los archivos de un directorio "fotos" y moverlos a un directorio "fotos2":

```
lista <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/user/Documents/fotos/")
for (archivo in lista){
  file.rename(from = archivo, to = paste("C:/Users/user/Desktop/fotos2/", archivo, sep = "") )
}
```

Este proceso depende del buen manejo del [directorio de trabajo](https://r-coder.com/directorio-trabajo-r/).

Ojalá sea de utilidad

Comment: Tu respuesta fue de gran ayuda, solamente tengo un inconveniente (creo que es por soy principiante en eso. Utilicé tu recomendación y se generan archivos, sin embargo están vacíos, comparto el código empleado para que me des tu opinión:

Comment: Creo que el error puede ser en la función paste, esta función une dos caracteres que en el ejemplo sirve para construir un path. Como en tu script usas la **~** para crear la lista de archivos, se está generando un path incorrecto al combinar los nombres de los archivos y del directorio destino, por ejemplo `~/ESTADISTICAS/MONITOREO/mtras_insat_imagenes/~/ESTADISTICAS/MONITOREO/imagen_2021/A032101359.JPG` creo que una solución es eliminar `"~/ESTADISTICAS/MONITOREO/imagen_2021` de la linea 5.

Comment: Además, podría faltar el argumento sep a la función paste: `for (archivo in f){   file.rename(from = archivo, to = paste("~/ESTADISTICAS/MONITOREO/mtras_insat_imagenes/", archivo, sep="") ) `